# Breaking .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

is there anyway to defy `.htaccess`? I mean to break what the rule written in the `.htaccess` file.

I have a directory, and I don't want others to browse it. So I created `.htaccess` file and wrote this

```
Deny from all
```

Is there anyway people can break it?

Comment: Apache can be configured so that .htaccess files are not used at all

Comment: so you mean, it needs the server to be hack in order to break `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope this is radical. Nobody can access it. It is safe and commonly used. The deny is made server side, so nobody can try to bypass it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I am now confident `.htaccess`.

Comment: @noobilityat19 Indeed `.htaccess` is something you can strongly rely on. :) Can you please mark this answer as accepted when you reach the 15 minutes delay? :) I would really appreciate :)

Comment: yes, definitely. I'm still waiting for the delay to expire so I can accept your answer

Comment: @noobilityat19 Thank you very much I appreciate this :) And hope to see you soon on the forum if you have any other questions :)

Comment: @ValentinMercier Q&A site. This is not a forum, nor should it be used as one. Also please note that internal rewrites can still expose the files inside the folder.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess files are as secure as Apache allows you to.

See for example, assuming your .htaccess file is located in /var/www/foo:

```
<Directory />
    Allow From All
    AllowOverride All # allow .htaccess files globally
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.foo.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/foo # impossible to access, thanks to .htaccess
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.bar.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/foo # same directory as above

     <Directory /var/www/foo>
         AllowOverride None # woops .htaccess will not be read, files can be accessed from this vhost
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Therefore there is no guarantee ever that your files are securely protected, as long as you don't know (and don't understand) how your apache installation is configured.